# What type should my field be to accept these values correctly in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the type of price field set to DECIMAL(10,2).
On my XML file that use to import the data to the database, I have values for price like 1,049.00, 399.99 and 550.

The 399.99 stays as is and the 550 becomes 550.00

However my question is how to set it correctly to accept 1,049.00 instead of showing me 1.00 ? Is it a database issue or from the PHP code?

Will be ok if I just set it to VARCHAR ?

Comment: Numbers shouldn't have commas in them; strip them out before inserting it into the database and you'll be fine.  You could store them as varchar, but that's not really correct; they are numbers.  You'd lose the ability to treat them as numbers in queries (e.g. by ordering or performing mathematical operations on them) if you store them that way.

Comment: If the 1,049.00 will be 1.049.00 it will be ok with math operations ?

Comment: 1.049.00 is mixing two notations. 1049.00 is the correct form. Just don't try to save the thousands seperator in the database, format it in your application.

Comment: @JPampos Well, no, as this is not a number anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want your MySQL field type to be is 'Double'

Comment: `Double` has its own set of "problems" - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html. It is up to the context if they are relevant or not.